# How to Visualise Cartesian Product of Vectors (Deep Learning)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading "Deep Learning" by Yoshua Bengio, and am getting stumped by this explanation of vectors.

"If each element is in R, and the vector has n elements, then the vector lies in the set formed by taking the Cartesian product of R n times, denoted as R^(n)."

I tried reading up on cartesian product, which was supposed to be the set of all ordered products. But I'm struggling with visualising / understanding this in the first place. Isn't there only one set of elements? What are we multiplying against? Could someone help me visualise / break this down for me please? Thanks!

Comment: You need not get hung up on the expression Cartesian product.  All it means is take $n$ elements, each one from $\mathbb R$.  That is written down as $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^2 = \{ (x,y); x, y \in \mathbb R\}$ and $\mathbb R \times \cdots \times\mathbb R = \mathbb R^n = \{(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n): x_i \in \mathbb R, i=1,2,\cdots,n\}$.  Just think of each point as $n$ coordinates.

Comment: @WADon That makes much more sense, thank you! So to clarify, we're using the R symbol, simply because each "element" is a real number?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is the case.

Comment: @WADon got it, thank you! sorry for all the questions, but would you mind explaining why the "R"s are multiplied against each other? What do the multiplication signs signify? Is it just convention?

Comment: I think it is just convention, and I am aware that there is a better justification.  One slight motivation is that in as you increase dimensions, the area / volume of a rectangle / cube is the product of the lengths of its sides, which forms some sort of analogue between using a notional product of $\mathbb R$ to represent multiple dimensions.